# What can be connected to an SGMII port?

Tags: pcb, ethernet

I would like to have an ethernet switch on a PCB so that I could connect a 2.5gbe to it, another one gigabit PHY and then connect it to a PCIe.

I checked out this switch:

https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/VSC7410

On its documentation, it says that it has 2x2.5gbe SGMII ports. I wonder if one of these ports can be connected to a 2.5gbe PHY and the other to a PCIe. Is that doable?

EDITED for clarification: [image: Block diagram]

I can't seem to find a 2.5gbps ethernet controller that could be a bridge between the SGMII+ port and PCIe. That's why I am adding another PHY to it. It seems that every ethernet controller I find out there has everything integrated into one pack (MAC, PHY and PCIe).

Comment: I’m trying to understand what you are trying to achieve? If your only have a Gigabit MAC, what’s the point of adding a 2.5G anything in front of it (if you only use 2 ports)? Or will you also use the remaining 4 Gbit ports?

Comment: Thanks @jcaron. I don't need the other gigabit ports. As I said on the question, I would like to connect one PHY to one of the 2.5gb ports, another to the host via PCI, and the host´s PHY into one of the switch´s PHY.

Comment: I think you should add a schematic, because the description in the comment seems to differ a bit from that in the question (and actually the first and last paragraphs of your question don't quite align either). My understanding was that you wanted 2.5 G interface <-> 2.5G PHY <-> port 1 - switch - port 2 <-> 1G MAC (host) <-> PCIe. But that doesn't tell us why you want to do that. You don't gain anything compared to 1 G interface <-> 1G PHY <-> 1 MAC (host) <-> PCIe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "MAC/PCIe". Ethernet and PCIe are two differents standards. So either you have an FPGA or CPU/MCU that you connect to Ethernet and that will do a bridge to PCIe, either you use an Ethernet controller that will form a bridge between these standards.

For 2.5Gbps Ethernet you can look at Intel I225 Ethernet controllers: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/ethernet/gigabit-controllers/i225-controllers.html

Marvell has also some controllers (from Aquantia), for instance AQC112C: https://www.marvell.com/products/ethernet-adapters-and-controllers.html

But you'll need to have a CPU/MCU on the PCIe side with SW and drivers to manage the Ethernet controller.

So yeah with the switch you can have up to 2 x 1G copper without external PHY, then 2 other 1G Ethernet through SGMII and finally 2 x 2.5G SGMII, you can connect on these two ports one to a 2.5G PHY through SGMII and the second one to an Ethernet controller.
The Ethernet connection will be done on the PCB with tracks.

This drawing shows a possible use case (very high level, need to look the datasheet in details for any other limitation):
[image]

Edit: I225 and AQC112C are for copper link so you can't connect them directly to switch with SGMII. In this case several alternative solutions (again very high level there might be restriction):

- Use a switch with 10G ports (ie VSC7437) and a 10G controller
- Use a 1G only switch and a dual 1G port controller you may look for link aggregation possibility. You won't have 2.5G and with aggregation you'll be close to 1.8G than 2G.
- Use a 2.5G copper PHY on switch side and connect to Ethernet controller copper side through PCB tracks

Comment: Thanks a lot @zeqL. My main problem is that I can't find a 2.5gbps ethernet controller that does't have an integrated PHY. The ethernet controllers you mention (Marvell/Aquantia and Intel i225) have all-in-one pack, so they won't for a bridge between PCIe and SGMII+.

Comment: @francisaugusto yeah I was a bit too fast. 2.5G and 5G are mostly copper standards so there is no controller with 2.5G/5G SGMII or equivalent. I've edited my answer with alternatives

Comment: Thanks a lot @zeql. I think your third alternative (using a PHY to connect the switch to an ethernet controller) might be the most doable and with a better cost.